# What does "take" in this sentence mean?

Tags: grammar

On a TV program, an immigration officer said to an immigrant as follows:
C1: Take four of your fingers and put ’em on the pad.

The pad was an electronic device which had a glass plate on its top and was about seven inches deep, five inches wide, and five inches tall. The immigration officer wanted the immigrant to put four of his fingers on the glass plate. I thought the device would get fingerprints by using light.

What motion or action does “take” of C1 mean?

Comment: ***Take*** doesn't "mean" much here - it's used to suggest the style of a ***recipe*** (cookery instructions). As in this one for a 1920s "flapper": [*“Take two bare knees, two rolled stockings, two flapping goloshes, one short skirt, one lipstick, one powder puff, 33 cigarettes, and a boy friend with flask. Season with a pinch of salt and dash of pep, and cover all with some spicy sauce, and you have the old-time flapper.”*](http://f4shion20s.tumblr.com/post/44691359180/take-two-bare-knees-two-rolled-stockings-two)

Comment: Geez, when you look at our language from the outside .... we're frickin *weird*.

Comment: And "from the outside" is relative. Some British speakers find the American expression "Watch your head" rather strange.

Comment: *Take* is the Swiss Army Knife of words.

Comment: @DanBron and when you *take* a look at our language ... :)

Answer (score 4):

In this usage, "put" is the action.  Take doesn't refer to an action.  It means "use".

More generally, this is using "take" to specify an object.  Another form of this is when "take" means to consider as in "English is complicated.  Take verbs for instance."  This alternate meaning of "take" is the key to the famous line from a joke by Henny Youngman "Take my wife.  Please."

When a recipe uses "take", it's not used just to specify an object.  There is an action involved, getting the ingredient from where it is.

Answer (score 0):

This usage is connected to the number of fingers, and is defined as #6 under **take** on [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/take)

> to pick from a number; select:
>   *Take whichever you wish.*

Comment: Disagree.  **Take**, here, is being used in the same meaning as in ¨Take this job and shove it¨.  Yes, **four** indicates selection and that is a joke (possibly at the immigrant´s expense) since four is all there are, but selection is added by inclusion of the number, not in **take**.  The meaning is closer to what Tim Ostrander has said.

Comment: Why couldn't he have taken two fingers or one finger and scanned that?

Comment: Because he was told to use four.  That doesn't change what I said.  The guard could have said "Press four of your fingers on the pad"; that would not mean that "press" carries any meaning of select.  My suggestion is that neither does take, here, really.

Comment: "Pick" is one meaning of "take" in this usage, but it is the secondary one.  The sentence would mean the same if it was "Take your right hand ...", showing that the main meaning is to specify an object for the following verb.

BTW, since there are only 4 fingers to pick from, this usage is a humor device.  This type of understated humor is more common in British English.

Answer (score 0):

A better understanding of "take" here is "prepare" or "get under one's control". That would be definition 3 here: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/take

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is the *core* meaning with a structuring/control idea(*prepare* indeed) as opposed to a figurative use of the third meaning referenced to by *Dictionary.com* and discussed in [another](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/210453/98955) answer([*Century*](http://triggs.djvu.org/century-dictionary.com/djvu2jpgframes.php?volno=07&page=846)):

> I. trans. 1. To lay hold of with the hand, fingers, arms, mouth or
>   other means of holding; grasp; seize.
>
> *Oure lorde, had hym take the vessell whiche that he hadde, and set it vpon the table.*

It is such a treat to peruse the pages of meanings here. For instance to [*take up*](http://triggs.djvu.org/century-dictionary.com/djvu2jpgframes.php?volno=07&page=849), which is related to the third meaning alluded to previously:

> a) To pick up; lift; raise.[...]
>
> i) To catch together and fasten: as in, to take up an artery; to take
>   up dropped stitches. [...]

Personally, I don't see why *choosing/selecting* couldn't contribute conceptually. It is the 8th meaning in *Century*. Or to *ascertain by computation or measurement*, 26th; 31th, rare, *to give, deliver*; 34th, to *conduct, escort, lead or carry*. Take your pick!

Comment: Sure it takes courage to explain why you downvote someone when there is effort. Anytime.

Answer (score -1):

MY ANSWER MAYBE FOR THE WORD TAKE IS SOMETHING YOU CAN TAKE OR YOU CAN DO 
EXAMPLE:I TAKE THE BUS FOR SCHOOL
OR I TOOK YOUR MONEY WHEN I SAW IT

Comment: Hi and welcome to EL&U.
Rule #0: Drop caps before you start typing something, or others would assume you're yelling or insulting.